# Project tango : Point cloud deformation at start

Tags: point-clouds, google-project-tango

I'm developping an application for the tango project. During the first seconds of point cloud acquision, there is a large deformation as if intrinsecs parameters of the depth camera were not good. I do not understand how to fix the problem. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the pose estimation. The tango uses previous frames to estimate where in the scene it is located (through structure from motion). These estimations are very approximative in the beginning, but gets more stable overtime as the tango is moved within the scene.

Since the estimated poses are slightly wrong - so will the point cloud be (the measurements are as correct as they can be, but the reference frame are wrong).

The easiest way to avoid bad point cloud data is to wait for a while after the application (and thereby the tango core) is started before you start acquiring depth data. During this time it helps if you move around the tango a bit (not too quickly) to give it as much data as possible to base its estimation on. Once it has a good estimation of the pose, the acquisition of point cloud data will be a lot more stable.

I know this is a ugly solution but I think that it is the one that most of us uses.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)